# Firefox Addons and message passing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any message passing mechanism between JavaScript code in a visiting page and a Firefox extension? (like [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) messaging API for Chrome apps)

Comment: Yes there are multiple ways, and each way suits a different purpose. Can you be more specific. Do you want to make it so any website can access a function from your addon?

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for your response! Yes, I want to create a communication port in the extension so that any website can connect to the port and then send and receive messages to/from the extension. I have read [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts) but, it seems that the extension cannot talk to webpage Javascript code.

Comment: This is the very easy way, `Cu.exportFunction` :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction

Comment: @Noitidart Thank you so much it seems to be promising!. Could you please put it as answer?

Comment: If you're already using the addon sdk, exportFunction is available to you in content scripts, see [this blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/).